# Percentages in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Using this query,

```
SELECT company, YEAR( date )  as year, COUNT( * ) as total
FROM table
WHERE company = "Medtronic"
OR company = "Private"
GROUP BY YEAR( date )
```

I get a table like this:

```
Company         year    total
Medtronic   1998    6
Private     1998    5
Medtronic   1999    5
Private     1999    1
```

How do I calculate the % that is contributed by each company for each year?

For example, the percentage contributed by Medtronic in year 1998 is 
6 / (6+5) = 54.5%

I have been trying to make a MySQL query to calculate the percentages.

Thanks guys.

Comment: @SQL Student: Can you post a few examples?  The percentages not coming out sounds really odd, especially if the total per company is correct.

Comment: I edited your code to remove some syntax errors, the example is posted in the 2nd answer below, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
SELECT x.company,
       x.year,
       x.annual_total
       x.annual_total / y.total AS percentage
  FROM (SELECT t.company, 
               YEAR(t.date) as year, 
               COUNT( * ) as annual_total
          FROM TABLE t
         WHERE t.company IN ('Medtronic', 'Private')
      GROUP BY YEAR( t.date ) ) x
  JOIN (SELECT t.company,
               COUNT(*) 'total'
          FROM TABLE t
         WHERE t.company IN ('Medtronic', 'Private')
      GROUP BY t.company) y ON y.company = x.company
```

If you want the percentage with particular decimal places, use:

```
CAST(x.annual_total / y.total AS DECIMAL(2,2)) AS percentage
```

Check that this gives the count per company you expect:

```
  SELECT t.company,
         COUNT(*) 'total'
    FROM TABLE t
   WHERE t.company IN ('Medtronic', 'Private')
GROUP BY t.company
```

Comment: Sorry, this might sound like a stupid question, but

what does "x" in "x.year" and "y" in "y.year" and "t" in "t.company" stand for? Do I replace the "t" with table names and "y" with column names?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not stupid at all.  `x` and `y` are table aliases, same as `t`.  It's just shorthand you can use to reference tables without having to type the full name.  It's required when you have identically named columns, and when you are joining a table onto itself.

Comment: I have done some modifications to the solution you gave me as another answer shown below (it would look bad in a comment), however the result is quite far off. Did I make a mistake somewhere? Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: sorry, it's still not working out, i'll attempt to find the error and will post the solution (if I find it). The last part of the code you posted gives the correct count per company though =) However, the % are off

Answer (score 0):

My SQL query:

```
SELECT x.company, x.year, x.annual_total, CAST( x.annual_total / y.total AS DECIMAL( 2, 2 ) ) AS percentage
FROM (

SELECT t.company, YEAR( t.date ) AS year, COUNT( * ) AS annual_total
FROM my_patents AS t
WHERE t.company = 'Private'
GROUP BY YEAR( t.date )
)x
JOIN (

SELECT t.company, COUNT( * ) AS total
FROM my_patents AS t
WHERE t.company = 'Medtronic'
OR t.company = 'Private'
GROUP BY t.company
)y ON y.company = x.company
```

my results:

```
Private  1998  5  0.04
```

when i run this query:

```
SELECT t.company, YEAR( date ) , COUNT( * ) AS total
FROM my_patents AS t
WHERE t.company = 'Medtronic'
OR t.company = 'Private'
GROUP BY t.company, YEAR( date )
```

I get

```
Medtronic  1998  6
Private  1998  5
```