# How can I select all the values of a database and choose one of them by a percent

Tags: php, mysql, database

What I want to do is to select a value of the database,

Lets say:

```
id ---- giftid ---- userid
1         1           481
2         1           422
3         7           123
4         9           542
5         1           122
6         1           455
```

For example, there are 4 users that want to have the same giftid:
1, 2, 5, 6

It means that each one will have 25% to be chosen.

How can I make the "percent selection"?

Comment: [Percentages in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878469/percentages-in-mysql)

Comment: What do you mean "choose one of them by a percent"? Are you talking about returning a single row from multiple rows chosen by a given probability?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every `userid` can only claim a `giftid` once, you can use the `ORDER BY RAND()` in MySQL. This will firstly select all the rows from table `table` where the giftid is `1` and then the results are ordered randomly. The `LIMIT 1` ensures that only the first record is returned

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE giftid = `1`
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: But as I know, the ORDER BY RAND() just selecting random field of these 4.

Comment: That is the same if you assign the `25%` chance to get chosen if every user can only claim the giftid once. Of course if your problem gets more complicated, for instance a single user can have multiple rows and hence the user distribution is not uniform, than this solution will not provide a uniformly random distrubtion

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking this?

```
SELECT giftid, 1.0 / COUNT(*) percentSelection
FROM tableName
GROUP BY giftid
```